# How many bits will be needed to multiply two 129 word numbers if the machine has 64 bit words?

Tags: algorithm, bit

So, I was studying and came across this algorithms question:

So, the machine uses 64 bits for words. We can multiply two n word numbers with a certain complexity. If n is 129, how many bits is that?

I'm a bit confused on how to do this. If a word is 64 bits, then I thought 129 * 64 would be the answer, but that seems like a very high number of bits. Can anyone explain how to approach this program?

Comment: What is the width in bits of an instruction?

Comment: The result of multiplying two 129 word/bit/byte/digit numbers can be up to 258 words/bits/bytes/digits wide

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying an N-bit number by an M-bit number yields an N+M-bit number. So to multiply a number of 129 words (8256 bits) by another yields a result of 16512 bits or 258 words. Yes, that's a lot of bits, but such multiplications appear in cryptography, for example.